# WPF: Change HeaderedContentControl orientation

Tags: wpf, orientation

Is there a way to change the orientation of the Header and the Content in a HeaderedContentControl?.
This is what I need to do: 
[image]

Can someone give me a hand??

Comment: Post your current XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UserControl with something like the following as it's content :

Inside a UC (or any Template or way you may desire to wrap it in)  :

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Background="Green">
        <TextBlock Text="Some Title" Background="Transparent" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>          
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>                        
        </TextBlock>        
    </Grid>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" />    <!-- Or Any Content you may desire -->      
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>   
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just solved it by using a grid as everyone does!
I created a grid with several columns and and I took the first column for working as the header. As you can see I had to rotate the text inside using a RenderTransform, but i looks pretty fine for me.
I know this is not answering the real question with the HeaderedContentControl, but for my task was the solution.
Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid >
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Column="0" Background="#009999">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Strand.Description,FallbackValue='Strand X'}" FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        
        <Grid Column="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.55*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.45*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource SubHeader}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.Variables}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource GridKeyCell}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.OperationMode}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}" MinWidth="50" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCellHighRelevance}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource GridKeyCell}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.Speed}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}" MinWidth="50" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource GridKeyCell}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.Direction}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}" MinWidth="50" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource GridKeyCell}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="50" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        
        <Grid Column="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.55*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Source="../Style/Images/Withdrawal - DummyBar.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="105" Width="45"></Image>
                
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource SubHeader}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.Machine4}" TextAlignment="Center"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource GridKeyCell}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.PressurePSI}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Style="{StaticResource GridKeyCell}" Text="{x:Static Localization:LanguageResource.Current}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource GridValueCell}" Text="{Binding FALTA,FallbackValue='---'}"/>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>            
    </Grid>
```

I didn't bind the data... where says 'FALTA' you just read any property you want.
Thanks everyone for the answers!!